# How do I give Blender rights to launch software to edit images in Windows 10?

Tags: external-applications

I wanted to edit a texture.
 
I go to preferences file path image editor select the location of Photoshop.exe
I go to the UV editor > Image > Edit externally
 
I have other software that can and do launch Photoshop.

I have tried to open files that Photoshop cannot open it still launches Photoshop, then shows a warning that it cannot open. I cannot even get that far with Blender.

How do I give rights / permission for Blender to open Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: These are the correct steps, works as expected here. Have you tried with factory settings? Perhaps some other add-on or something else is causing a conflict?

Comment: @Timaroberts I am using Blender 2.81a, Windows v1903 maybe mine is different than yours?

Comment: No, I'm running the same with Photoshop 2020. Any version of blender works as expected actually, whether installed 2.81a or other portable versions.

Comment: @Timaroberts If I find Photoshop.exe manually it doesn't work. If I right click on the shortcut for Photoshop and copy Target location address. then it works.

Comment: @Timaroberts I wrote the address wrong or added the quotes from the target box or something. Now it works as it is suppose to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs specify here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/file_paths.html)
You go to preferences > file paths.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/179573)

Comment: Hello, emotional, and @HarryMcKenzie.. I think we have to rely on official docs links not breaking, that's fine. And, if you substitute 'latest' for the version  number in a link to the docs, then the link will  point to the most recent version. Sometimes wanted, sometimes not.